# AADB2C90304 User journey went into a bad state. Claims exchange with id 'LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange' could not be found in orchestration step '2'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am creating users using Microsoft Graph API as follows

```cs
var userToAddToAAD = new User
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = $"{firstName} {lastName}",
    MailNickname = $"{firstName}{lastName[0]}",
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
        Password = password
    },
    Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>
    {
        new ObjectIdentity
        {
            SignInType = "emailAddress",
            Issuer = _issuer,
            IssuerAssignedId = emailAddress,
        }
    }
};

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(_tenantId, _testboltDevClientApiClientId, _testboltDevClientApiClientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var newUser = await graphClient.Users.PostAsync(userToAddToAAD);
```

After new user sign in, i have to enable reset password flow. To do that I have created a custom polices as follows.

https://learn-attachment.microsoft.com/api/attachments/1051649b-b8f2-4fff-9f40-6258630e6e9e?platform=QnA

With this, when user sign in I was able to redirect to password reset and then user can update the password. But after that I am getting following error.

[image]

I need a solution for this. Can someone help me to solve this?